# How to iterate by priority?

Tags: java, iterator

In java let say I have a class called ExampleClass, which has a collection of a class called Item. Each item has an integer in a field called ID. How can I have the iterator of ExampleClass iterate through Items with even IDs and then iterate through Items with Odd IDs.

Edit: I don't need an answer to this specific problem, I am asking generally how to have an Iterator inner class in ExampleClass 
that will iterate through items with one property first and then through the others.

Comment: `items.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.getID() % 2)).iterator()`

Comment: @shmosel too bad it cannot be upvoted or accepted as the answer, since you post answer as comment...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following if condition to check if the ID is odd or not:

```
for(int i = 0;i < maxID;i++) { //I'm not sure what your maximum ID is.
  if(Item.ID % 2 == 0) {
    //Iterate
  }
}
```

Then, you can do the same thing for odd IDs:

```
for(int i = 0;i < maxID;i++) { //I'm not sure what your maximum ID is.
  if(Item.ID % 2 == 1) {
    //Iterate
  }
}
```

The code `Item.ID % 2` divides the ID by 2, and returns the remainder. In the if statement, it checks to see if the remainder is 0. If it is, then the ID is even, and it runs the desired code. However, if the remainder is 1, then the number is odd.

Example: `4 / 2 = 2`. The remainder is 0. Therefore, the number `4` is even.

Example: `5 / 2 = 2`. The remainder is 1. Therefore, the number `5` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you can go about it with 1 liners.

```
final Iterator<Item> it = items.stream().filter(i.getID() % 2 == 0).iterator();
```

or

```
for (final Item i : items.stream().filter(i.getID() % 2 == 0).toArray())
     doSomethingWith(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to iterate through them in any specific order, you will need to make the array of items ordered before you loop through them. How you go about that is up to you based on your application and ordering needs. I suggest something which resembles the pseudocode:

```
unsortedArray[]
sortedArray[]

for (every element in unsortedArray) {
    id = element.ID; //Or sort value calculated with some other method
    sortedIndexBeforeID = sortedArray.findLastElementWithIDBelow(id); //Get the index of sorted element with an ID just before ours.
    sortedArray.insert(element,sortedIDBeforeID); //Add the element into the sorted array at given index, pushing the rest of the elements around
}

sortedArray[]
```